# How to save a plot by Gadfly.jl without displaying

Tags: plot, ggplot2, julia

```
using Gadfly
myplot = plot(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, Geom.line)
draw(PNG("myplot.png", 3inch, 3inch), myplot)
```

I just want to make a png file without displaying anything in browsers. (Why? For example, I am working at a remote server.)
How can I stop the function `plot` from displaying the figure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind. I just found out the answer in https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/479.

I need to add a semicolon to the end the line, e.g.

```
myplot = plot(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, Geom.line);
draw(PNG("myplot.png", 3inch, 3inch), myplot)
```